# Cannot add parent publication to newly created blank publication

Tags: blueprint

I am not able to add a parent publication. I have created the blank publication and the root structure group. after that, I want to inherit from my parent publication, but no option appears when I open the blue printing. Only the child publication option appears, and that is disabled.

I have created a root folder. The child publication option is enabled.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you don't add at least one parent publication when creating it, you will not be able to do so later on. This is one of the restrictions Tridion.